# Adding a new user, will not enter in database or display results

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I am trying to enter a new user to a system using a username and password field and a button.  When I enter credential I get no response at all, not even an error message.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $logged_in = isset($_SESSION['USERNAME']) && $_SESSION['USERNAME'] ?    
    $_SESSION['USERNAME'] : null;
    if(!$logged_in) {
    header("location:index.php");   
    }
    include 'dbsettings.php';

    // username and password sent from form in login.php
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

   // encrypting password
    $encrypted_password=md5($password);

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->execute(array($username)); 
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if (! $row){

  //add new user to database
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO user_info(username, password) VALUES (?,?)");
  $params1 = array($username, $encrypted_password);

  if (!$stmt ->execute($params1)){
echo "user has not been entered on the database check with administrator of the system.    
<span class='label label-important'>Important</span>";

}else{
echo $username." has been added to the database as admin. <span class='label  
label-success'>Success</span>";

//send an email to the user


session_start();
$_SESSION['USERNAME']=$username;
$_SESSION['PASSWORD']=$encrypted_password;

}

}else{
        echo $username." is already a supervisor register in the PPM tool. <span class='label label-warning'>Warning</span>";

}
$dbh = null; 
?>
```

This is the target of the form and the form itself:

```
 <form name="form1" method="post" action="adduser.php" >


 <input type="text"  placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username">
 <input type="password"  placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password"> 
 <button class="btn btn-primary addSupervisor" type="button">Add new  
 user</button>

  </form>
```

Can you see any reason why this is not working?

Comment: debug it - as a start - by `var_dump($row);`everytime you use it. Apart from that, md5 is not considered a safe method, you'll find some high-quality articles here on SO.

Comment: Do you have `display_errors` enabled and `error_reporting(E_ALL)`?

Comment: hmm..`button` doesn't submit form

Comment: @redreggae - indeed. OP, you need `<input type="submit" value="Add new user" class="whatever" />` here.

Comment: Oh my goodness, can't believe I missed that, I have changed it to input and it will  not display the var_dump. this error occurs.....Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in on this line: $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE username = ?");

Comment: or `button type="submit"` would work in most browsers

Comment: @user1830632: have you initialised the `$dbh` object? I guess that might be in "dbsettings.php", but it's not in the code you've supplied.

Comment: Incidentally, when you use `header('Location: X')`, this does not in itself exit the script at that point. It just supplies an HTTP header to the browser. Thus, you need to follow this with an `exit()` as well.

Comment: I have changed it to global $db its not working, sadly the values are still not inserting despite no errors.

Comment: OK, take @michi's advice and debug - dump your variables and exit at various points, and see if the value you expect at each juncture is the one you get.

Comment: Please use sha256 with a proper salt instead of md5.

Answer (score 0):

add to top to force errors incase your settings have disabled it somehow:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Also it looks like you're calling session_start() a second time (after the comment send email to user), should look at that too.